# Remote SQL Server 2008 Management Studio is not connecting

Tags: webserver, instruction-set, sql-server-2008

Remote SQL Server 2008 Management Studio is not connecting to the database using TMG SERVER 2010. Error 40 and 53 are showing up.

But it is working without tmgserver.

Please advise.

Thanks